Functions are often said to be vectors, but is it the case that vectors are functions?
I've tried to search for the answer to this question, but I keep getting answers for the converse question of how functions can be seen as vectors, and how they relate to a more abstracted concept of vector spaces.
I can sort of follow the arguments, but to me it seems easier to say the opposite. That vectors are functions.

Vectors can be "placed" anywhere in $R^n$, not just at the origin.
All vectors of the same magnitude, direction, and dimension are
equivalent.
It seems a vector essentially takes a point and returns a
point like a function, but they do this for the entire space of
$R^n$ at once. For example, \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} can be seen as taking all the points in $R^2$ and doing $f(x)=x+2$ and $f(y)=y+2$.

It seems as if vectors are a notational simplification for applying a set of functions across an entire space.
Is there something I'm mistaken in, or something I'm missing? Is it possible both are true, but this way of viewing them is just less useful?
Any inputs or information of where my knowledge gaps may be and where to look for more information are much appreciated.

Functions aren't "vectors" in the sense of ordered tuples of real numbers (usually).  What they're likely talking about are vector spaces made up out of functions, not tuples.  For instance, there is the vector space of all continuous functions $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ under pointwise addition and scaling.  These "vectors" cannot be made into "traditional" vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Yet, they are called vectors because they are elements of a vector space.

Vectors aren't functions. Functions aren't vectors. I'm not sure where you get those ideas from, but this isn't even close to truth.

@freakish Functions can most definitely be vectors. For example, the $L^p$ spaces are classic examples of function spaces that are also topological vector spaces.

I see, so functions are not actually vectors in the traditional sense of how we view them, but can be an element of a vector space but why is it the case that vectors cannot be seen as functions? Do vectors not essentially apply a set of functions to a point? i.e. my example of <2,2> which results in (x+2,y+2)? This can be seen from the origin, but it can really be applied anywhere like a function, no? Please forgive me if I'm misunderstanding here.

@user24895674 There are several different notions of what a vector is: ① an element of Euclidean space (basically $ℝ^n$), ② A quantity with both magnitude and direction (basically an element of an inner product space) ③ An element of a vector space.
In mathematics, ③ is the default. In other fields and in colloquial usage, ① and ② are also used.

@Hyperplane thank you. I mostly come from a physics background so I suppose maybe my misunderstanding comes from viewing them more in line with notion 2. I will try to look elsewhere for resources to broaden my understanding from the mathematics perspective and in terms of vector spaces.

@Hyperplane the $L^p$ space is outside of the context of this question. It literally asks about $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In the context of an affine space $A$ and its associated vector space $\overrightarrow A$, you are right: vectors in $\overrightarrow A$ act on $A$ and in this respect, "are" (or: can be identified with) translations, which are maps from $A$ to itself.

The function $f(x)=x+c$ is different than the function $f(x)=c$ despite both involving a constant. So there is no unique function associated with a vector for this reason. Another common form of function created from a vector is a linear functional rather than a translation. So there is no single function associated with a vector.

It is quite reasonable to think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the set of functions ${1, \dots, n} \to \mathbb{R}$, but this does not match with the rest of the question.

Anything in mathematics can be thought of as a function (at least if it is an element of some set, for technical reasons). Have some random object $A$? It can be thought of as the function $f: {0} \to {A} : 0 \mapsto A$. In your case, you have some vector space $V$? It can be thought of as the space of all functions ${0} \to V$. This isn't just some petty trick either. It is a set-theoretic version of a basic and important concept of Category theory.
